# Why do we need to make sentences in a sequence lowercase in text generation applications? Or is it necessary at all?

Tags: python, deep-learning, text-files

Apparently i'm doing a project relating to text generation. According to the code sample from tensorflow.org, when load the text file, they do not lower the letters in their data. However, in other sources, for example deeplearningai's Dinosaurus_Island assignment in the Sequence Models course. I don't know the effect of lowering the letters in the text, or is there any effect at all?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory & methodology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason you may want to lowercase your text is if your dataset is small. Imagine the word 'amazing' and 'Amazing' appear in your dataset. To a neural net, these two are different words. If you have a big data set and these words appear multiple times in different cases, it might be able to learn that 'amazing' and 'Amazing' are the same thing. But let's say that the word 'amazing' appears ten times in your training set and 'Amazing' occurs only once. There is a high chance the model won't be able to figure out the relationship between the two and this might affect the network's performance.

Lower casing can also help with OOV words. Imagine if 'Amazing' never appeared in the training dataset but the network encounters it in a test sample. If you lowercase your inputs, it would work fine but if you don't, you'll have problems.

Comment: Your explanation seems to be clear to me, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

It's for simplifying how many elements need to be represented. When you have uppercase letters you need to allocate a minimum of 26 extra spaces [A-Z] or more if there are combinations of capital letters. For text classification, I don't think it's necessary to keep capitals as this doesn't affect how the text reads but in the case where you're trying to generate say the next word or next letter in the sequence then it becomes important.

Comment: Is adding more 26 capital letters more expensive to compute? Thanks you!

Comment: Depends I guess on the word structure in the vocabulary. For a simple problem wherein you're using single letters, it does not add heavily on the compute time.